# Rails select all record through related habtm tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

```
class User
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tag_groups
end

class Tag
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tag_groups
end

class TagGroup
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
end
```

Schema:

```
  create_table "tag_groups", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "tag_groups_flags", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "tag_id", null: false
    t.bigint "tag_group_id", null: false
  end

  create_table "tag_groups_homes", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "tag_group_id", null: false
    t.bigint "home_id", null: false
  end

  create_table "tags", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "tags_homes", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "tag_id"
    t.bigint "home_id"
  end
```

Data example:

```
  home = Home.create(name: "home 1")
  tag_1 = Tag.create(name: "tag 1")
  tag_2 = Tag.create(name: "tag 2")
  tag_3 = Tag.create(name: "tag 3")

  tag_group = TagGroup.create(name: "Tag Group")
  tag_group.tags << tag_3

  home.tags << tag_1
  home.tag_groups << tag_group

  home.all_tag_names # => "tag 1, tag 3, Tag Group" so it names of associated tags, tag groups and tags in those tag groups
```

So with the following setup i want to be able to select all tags associated to the user directly and through tag groups, and tag group names too.

with plain ruby i'm doing following

```
(tag_groups + tag_groups.map(&:tags).flatten + tags).map(&:name)
```

but i want to do it in one sql call if possible? Tried different approaches with joins and merges but had no luck, any ideas?

Comment: Yes it is quite possible. Show your sql setup in the question. Sample data and the desired output would help.

Comment: Added schema and example of data

Answer (score 0):

An SQL query for all distinct home-tag associations directly or through a group association.

```
select h.name homename, t.name tagname
from homes h
join tags_homes th on th.home_id = h.id
join tags t on t.id = th.tag_id

union

select h.name, t.name 
from homes h
join tag_groups_homes tgh on tgh.home_id = h.id
join tag_groups_flags tg on tg.tag_group_id = tgh.tag_group_id
join tags t on t.id = tg.tag_id
```